# is it possible to edit crystal report formula in C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

is it possible to change or editing formula dynamically from user

for example :

```
  CrystalReportValue1.ViewInfo.PageNumber = textbox.text ;
```

i want the user can edit page numbering so he can start from any number he want

so is it possible to change formula field ?

Comment: Unclear - do you want display own/changed page numbers OR start displaying report from specific page?

Comment: i want the user to decide what [page number] the report will started

Comment: If you have 3-page report and user enters 4, then do you want to see same three pages with numbers 4, 5, 6? (Sorry my english is poor, I rather ask over that misunderstand.)

Comment: Why don't you use Parameter instead..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to jump to a certain page in the Crystal Report you can use this:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ShowNthPage(Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text));
```